# Access a php array of indexed objects with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php array of objects istantiated from the following class:

```
class my_class {
    public $id;
    public $timestamp;
}
```

These are stored in an array with indexes 0,1,2.....

I am getting this array with jquery through the Session variable and I attempt to print it in the following ways:

```
var myclass_map = "<?php $_SESSION['myclass_map']?>";
$.each(myclass_map, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ' ' + value["id"]);
});
```

and

```
var track_map = "<?php $_SESSION['myclass_map']?>";
$.each(myclass_map, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key + ' ' + value.id);
});
```

but both give me an undefined reference to value while the print out the key. How can I access the objects variables?

Comment: You are confusing `asp` with `php` - 2 different things.

Comment: Besides do you really need jQuery to loop thourgh an array??

Comment: Unfortunately I need it. I also Edited the question, using php this time!

Comment: You have some strange PHP version installed on your system.

Comment: I see your point, I edited again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very begining of your JS script, print the array converted to js format, using json_encode.

```
var track_map = <?=json_encode($map)?>;
```

Comment: it seems as the correct approach, but isn't there any quotes or something similar missing? I am using the following :                     var map = "<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['map'] )?>";